# Spring boot AuthenticationSuccessHandler ignored

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Hello Stackoverflower,

I've got a Issue with the Spring Security AuthenticationSuccessHandler. I implemented a custom AuthenticationSuccessHandler but It's ignored when an user logged successful.

My Custom AuthenticationSuccessHandler class:

```
 @Component("customSuccessHandler")
 public class CustomSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {



/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationSuccessHandler#onAuthenticationSuccess(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse, org.springframework.security.core.Authentication)
 */
@Override
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {



    System.out.println("***************************************************!!!!");
    System.out.println("Logged Successful!!!!");
    System.out.println("************************************!!!!");

    //Ajout des informations utilisateur à la session
    ajouterInformationsUtilisateurEnSession(request, authentication);



    String urlDeRedirection = determinerUrlDeRedirection(authentication);

    if (response.isCommitted()) {
        System.out.println("La reponse a ete commitée, redirection vers : " + urlDeRedirection);
        return;
    }

    response.sendRedirect(urlDeRedirection);

}

private String determinerUrlDeRedirection(Authentication auth) {

    Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = auth.getAuthorities();

    List<String> roles = new ArrayList<>();

    for (GrantedAuthority authority : authorities) {
        System.out.println("ROLES : " + authority.getAuthority());

        roles.add(authority.getAuthority());
    }

    if (roles.contains("ROLE_ADMIN")) {
        return "/ajouterattributaire";
    } else if (roles.contains("ROLE_DGA")) {
        return "/home";
    } else {
        return "/error/403";
    }

}

private void ajouterInformationsUtilisateurEnSession(HttpServletRequest request, Authentication authentication) {

    //Récupération Session
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();

    //Définition des informations utilisateur à mettre en session : identifiant et roles 

    //Identifiant utilisateur
    String identifiant = authentication.getName();

    //Roles
    List<String> roles = new ArrayList<>();

    for (GrantedAuthority authority : authentication.getAuthorities()) {
        roles.add(authority.getAuthority());
    }

    //Ajout des infomations utilisateur à la session
    session.setAttribute("identifiant", identifiant); 
    session.setAttribute("roles", roles);
}}
```

My configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

/*@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;*/

private AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler;
private AuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler;
private AuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler;
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Autowired
public SecurityConfiguration( 
        @Qualifier("customAccessDeneiedHandler")AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler,
        @Qualifier("customSuccessHandler")AuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler,
        @Qualifier("customAuthenticationFailureHandler")AuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler,
        @Qualifier("customUserDetailsService")UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
    this.accessDeniedHandler = accessDeniedHandler;
    this.authenticationSuccessHandler = authenticationSuccessHandler;
    this.authenticationFailureHandler = authenticationFailureHandler;
    this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
}



/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter#configure(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder)
 */
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //super.configure(auth);

    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)   //auth.userDetailsService(utilisateurDetailsService)
        .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}

//Authorization
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
            //.antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/ajouterattributaire").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            //.httpBasic()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            //.loginProcessingUrl("/login")
            .usernameParameter("identifiant")
            .passwordParameter("mot_de_passe")
            .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler)
            .failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler)
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .logout().permitAll();

    http.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler);
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter#configure(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity)
 */
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**", "/static/**", "/css/**", "/images/**", "/var/signatures/**");
    //web.ignoring().antMatchers("/static/**");
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}}
```

My custom userDetailsService :

```
@Service("customUserDetailsService")
public class UtilisateurDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

@Autowired
private UtilisateurService utilisateurService;

@Autowired
private RoleService roleService;

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService#loadUserByUsername(java.lang.String)
 */
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String identifiantUtilisateur) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    Utilisateur utilisateur = utilisateurService.rechercherParIdentifiantUtilisateur(identifiantUtilisateur);

    if (utilisateur == null) {
        System.out.println("Problème d'authentification : " + new UsernameNotFoundException("Utilisateur Inexistant").getMessage());
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Ulisateur inexistant dans la base de donnees!");

    }    
    else {

        List<String> nomRoles = roleService.determinerListeDesRolesDeLUtilisateur(utilisateur.getIdUtilisateur());

        List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();

        List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> simpleGrantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<>();

        for (String nomRole : nomRoles) {  //"ROLE_" + 
            simpleGrantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + nomRole));
        }

        for (String nomRole : nomRoles) {
            roles.add(roleService.rechercherRoleParNomRole(nomRole));
        }

        //Affectation role à l'utilisateur
        utilisateur.setRoles(roles);

        System.out.println("*********************************************************************************");

        System.out.println("Id utilisateur : " + utilisateur.getIdUtilisateur());
        System.out.println("Identifiant : " + utilisateur.getIdentifiantUtilisateur());
        System.out.println("Nom : " + utilisateur.getNomUtilisateur());
        System.out.println("Mot de passe : " + utilisateur.getMotDePasseUtilisateur()); 
        System.out.println("Est actif : " + utilisateur.getEstActifUtilisateur());
        System.out.println("Signature utilisateur : " + utilisateur.getSignatureUtilisateur());
        System.out.println("Date création : " + utilisateur.getDateHeureCreationUtilisateur());
        System.out.println("Authoritises : " + utilisateur.getAuthorities());

        System.out.println("Roles : " + utilisateur.getRoles().isEmpty());

        System.out.println("Taille roles : " + utilisateur.getRoles().size());
        System.out.println("Roles : " + utilisateur.getRoles().isEmpty());

        for(Role role : utilisateur.getRoles()) {
            System.out.println("Role : " + role.getAuthority());
        }
        System.out.println("*********************************************************************************");

        //return utilisateur;
        /*User user = new User(utilisateur.getIdentifiantUtilisateur(), 
                            utilisateur.getMotDePasseUtilisateur(), 
                            simpleGrantedAuthorities);*/

        //return user;
        return utilisateur;
    }

}}
```

I don't know what wrong. I think the principale is OK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `CustomSuccessHandler` is overriden by default handler in your security config.

Just delete following line: `.defaultSuccessUrl("/")` from `SecurityConfiguration` class

Answer (score 0):

With Spring boot 2, first delete the *.defaultSuccessUrl("/")* and create the bean CustomSuccessHandler.

```
public AuthenticationSuccessHandler myCustomSuccessHandler(){
    return CustomSuccessHandler();
}
```